# telethon: how to check message delivery status?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I send a lot of messages to users. and I need to know which of the messages has been seen

I used `SearchRequest` but it doesn't have any staus about the message.

```
result = client(SearchRequest(
    peer=ahmad,  # On which chat/conversation
    q='',  # What to search for
    filter=InputMessagesFilterEmpty(),  # Filter to use (maybe filter for media)
    min_date=None,  # Minimum date
    max_date=None,  # Maximum date
    offset_id=0,  # ID of the message to use as offset
    add_offset=0,  # Additional offset
    limit=20,  # How many results
    max_id=0,  # Maximum message ID
    min_id=0,  # Minimum message ID
    from_id=None,  # Who must have sent the message (peer)
    hash=0  # Special number to return nothing on no-change
))

if result:
    print(result.count)

    for message in result.messages:
        print(message)

    for chat in result.chats:
        print(chat)

    for user in result.users:
        print(user)
```

output :

```
Message(id=299213, to_id=PeerUser(user_id=74509408), date=datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 7, 57, 9, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), message='hello', out=True, mentioned=False, media_unread=False, silent=False, post=False, from_id=74509408, fwd_from=None, via_bot_id=None, reply_to_msg_id=None, media=None, reply_markup=None, entities=[], views=None, edit_date=None, post_author=None, grouped_id=None)
```

also, `GetMessagesViewsRequest` just works for channel message, not user.

```
print(client(GetMessagesViewsRequest(
    peer=ahmad,
    id=[299049],
    increment=True
)))
```

output:

```
[0]
```

Comment: Hello Ahmady! welcome to stackoverflow. A tip for future questions is using proper formatting and including any code you might need help with. this will save you from the downvotes in future questions you might have

Comment: how do you solve the problem,i have the same?